# Copy Database from assets when there is a new database version

Tags: android, database, android-assets

I am trying to solve the following problem. I have an application which uses a pre-created database. I put this database in assets folder. Then i copy the database internaly.

I want to be able to check the version of my database so when there is a new version i delete the old database and copy the new one from assets folder. I store the database version as an shared preference data.

Runing the following code i got an error and the application stops running (has stopped unexpectendly). 
Can you please help me and find where the problem is?

```
   public class DatabaseConnector
     {
// database name
   private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "Recipes";
   private SQLiteDatabase database; // database object
   private DatabaseOpenHelper databaseOpenHelper; // database helper

   String selection;       

   // public constructor for DatabaseConnector
   public DatabaseConnector(Context context) 
   {
      // create a new DatabaseOpenHelper
      databaseOpenHelper = 
         new DatabaseOpenHelper(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, 1);
   } // end DatabaseConnector constructor

   // open the database connection
   // attempts to establish a connection to the db
   // and throws an exception if it fails
   public void open() throws SQLException 
   {
      // create or open a database for reading/writing
      database = databaseOpenHelper.getWritableDatabase();
   } // end method open

   // close the database connection
   public void close() 
   {
      if (database != null)
         database.close(); // close the database connection
   } // end method close

   // inserts a new esoda in the database
   public void insertEsoda(String title, String category, String ingredients, String process, 
      String notes, String image, String time, String calories, String difficulty) 
   {
....
   } // end method insertEsoda

   // updates a esoda in the database
   public void updateEsoda(long id, String title, String category, String ingredients, 
      String process, String notes, String image, String time, String calories, String difficulty) 
   {
      ....
   } // end method updateEsoda


// updates favorites in the database
   public Boolean updateFavorite(long id) 
   {
....
   } // end method update favorites


   // return a Cursor with all esoda information in the database
   public Cursor getAllEsoda() 
   {
     ....
   } // end method getAllEsoda


   // return a Cursor with all esoda information in the database
   public Cursor getRecipeCategory(int position) 
   {
      ....
   } // end method getAllEsoda


   // get a Cursor containing all information about the esoda specified
   // by the given id
   public Cursor getOneEsoda(long id) 
   {
     ....
   } // end method getOneEsoda


   // delete the contact specified by the given String name
   public void deleteEsoda(long id) 
   {
     ....
   } // end method deleteEsoda


   private class DatabaseOpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
       public Context mContext;
       private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
       private static final String SP_KEY_DB_VER = "db_ver";

      // public constructor
      public DatabaseOpenHelper(Context context, String title,
         CursorFactory factory, int version) 
      {
         super(context, title, factory, version);
         mContext=context;
         initialize();
      } // end DatabaseOpenHelper constructor

      private void initialize() {

          if (databaseExists()) {
              SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                      .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
              int dbVersion = prefs.getInt(SP_KEY_DB_VER, 1);
              if (DATABASE_VERSION != dbVersion) {
                  File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
                  if (!dbFile.delete()) {
                      Log.w("TAG", "Unable to update database");
                  }
              }
          }
          if (!databaseExists()) {
              createDatabase();
          }
      }

      private boolean databaseExists() {
          File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);
          return dbFile.exists();
      }

      private void createDatabase() {
          String parentPath = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getParent();
          String path = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).getPath();

          File file = new File(parentPath);
          if (!file.exists()) {
              if (!file.mkdir()) {
                  Log.w("TAG", "Unable to create database directory");
                  return;
              }
          }

          InputStream is = null;
          OutputStream os = null;
          try {
              is = mContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
              os = new FileOutputStream(path);

              byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
              int length;
              while ((length = is.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                  os.write(buffer, 0, length);
              }
              os.flush();
              SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager
                      .getDefaultSharedPreferences(mContext);
              SharedPreferences.Editor editor = prefs.edit();
              editor.putInt(SP_KEY_DB_VER, DATABASE_VERSION);
              editor.commit();
          } catch (IOException e) {
              e.printStackTrace();
          } finally {
              if (is != null) {
                  try {
                      is.close();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
              if (os != null) {
                  try {
                      os.close();
                  } catch (IOException e) {
                      e.printStackTrace();
                  }
              }
          }
      }



      // creates the contacts table when the database is created
      @Override
      public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
      {
         // query to create a new table named contacts
         String createQuery = "CREATE TABLE recipes" +
            "(_id integer primary key autoincrement," +
            "title TEXT, category TEXT, ingredients TEXT, process TEXT, notes TEXT, image TEXT, " +
            "time TEXT, calories TEXT, difficulty TEXT);";

         db.execSQL(createQuery); // execute the query
      } // end method onCreate

      @Override
      public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, 
          int newVersion) 
      {
      } // end method onUpgrade
   } // end class DatabaseOpenHelper
}
```

This is my LogCat text:

```
11-27 23:19:41.643: D/AndroidRuntime(297): Shutting down VM
11-27 23:19:41.643: W/dalvikvm(297): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x4001d800)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{development.nk.cretanrecipes/development.nk.cretanrecipes.RecipesMainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2585)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at development.nk.cretanrecipes.DatabaseConnector$DatabaseOpenHelper.initialize(DatabaseConnector.java:191)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at development.nk.cretanrecipes.DatabaseConnector$DatabaseOpenHelper.<init>(DatabaseConnector.java:186)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at development.nk.cretanrecipes.DatabaseConnector.<init>(DatabaseConnector.java:35)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at development.nk.cretanrecipes.RecipesMainActivity.<init>(RecipesMainActivity.java:32)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at java.lang.Class.newInstanceImpl(Native Method)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:1429)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1021)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2577)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  ... 11 more
```

Comment: You need to include the error from the logcat output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error in the stacktrace seems to be related to a toast, which is not appearing in the code you pasted.

However, this library [sqllite asset helper](https://github.com/jgilfelt/android-sqlite-asset-helper) seems to address the same exact problem you are trying to solve.

"An Android helper class to manage database creation and version management using an application's raw asset files."

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the answer. There is no problem related to a toast. I will study the library..

Comment: According to the logcat you posted: 11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.content.ContextWrapper.getResources(ContextWrapper.java:80)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.widget.Toast.<init>(Toast.java:89)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at android.widget.Toast.makeText(Toast.java:231)

Comment: I removed all toasts but the problem remains. I think it has something to do with Context....

Comment: Are you using the context in the activity constructor instead of in its onCreate method? That might be the problem (I am pretty sure it is).

Comment: Yes but given your stacktrace you are calling its constructor in the RecipesMainActivity's constructor instead of RecipesMainActivity's onCreate method. I think at that stage the context is not ready yet

Comment: After some research i found that the problem is at that code line: "File dbFile = mContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME);"

Comment: Which is because you are calling the DatabaseConnector in RecipesMainActivity constructor instead of onCreate: 11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at development.nk.cretanrecipes.DatabaseConnector.<init>(DatabaseConnector.java:35)
11-27 23:19:41.673: E/AndroidRuntime(297):  at development.nk.cretanrecipes.RecipesMainActivity.<init>(RecipesMainActivity.java:32)

Comment: ok i called DatabaseConnector at onCreate and it worked... Now i have to solve other problems that occured after that change.. Thank you anyway...